# Marshal/Unmarshal custom type with mongodb-go-driver

Tags: mongodb, unmarshalling, mongo-go

So I'm trying out the official mongodb go driver (was using mgo before), and I'm stuck. I'm trying to marshal/unmarshal a custom type, which is obviously not working by default. The documentation is kind of lacking. Basically what I would like to do is this:

```
type X struct {
    Y Z
}


type Z interface {
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to do it, or does it completely lack this feature at this moment? I know it's still a beta release, but there isn't much alternative out there.

Edit:

Example what I would like to do:

```
cur, err := mongo.Collection("coll").Find(ctx, bson.M{})
if err != nil {
  return err
}
defer cur.Close(ctx)
for cur.Next(ctx) {
  var el X
  err := cur.Decode(&el)
  if err == nil {
    // Do whatever...
  }
}
if err = cur.Err(); err != nil {
  return err
}
```

And the error I get is: `no decoder found for Z`

Test example:

```
package examples

import (
    "context"
    "testing"

    "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson"
    "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo"
)

type X struct {
    Color string `json:"color" bson:"color"`
    Y     Z      `bson:"y"`
}

type Z interface {
    echo() string
}

func (x X) echo() string {
    return x.Color
}

func TestFindCars(t *testing.T) {
    var err error
    var client *mongo.Client
    var collection *mongo.Collection
    var cur mongo.Cursor
    var ctx = context.Background()
    if client, err = mongo.Connect(ctx, "mongodb://localhost/so?replicaSet=replset"); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    collection = client.Database("so").Collection(collectionName)
    collection.InsertOne(ctx, bson.M{"color": "Red", "y": 12})
    if cur, err = collection.Find(ctx, bson.M{}); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer cur.Close(ctx)
    for cur.Next(ctx) {
        var el X
        if err = cur.Decode(&el); err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
        }
        t.Log(el.echo())
    }
    if err = cur.Err(); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why isn't it correct? The `...` part just means there are a couple methods, but it could be empty, doesn't really matter.

Comment: Show an example on what you intend to do.

Comment: Added a simple example with error message.

Comment: What version of mongo-go-driver do you have?  I don't have the error you had.  Do you import from "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson"?

Comment: I've done a go get yesterday, so it should be up to date. Yes, I do import it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example using your example and it ran fine.

```
package examples

import (
    "context"
    "testing"

    "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson"
    "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo"
)

type X struct {
    Color string `json:"color" bson:"color"`
    Y     Z
}

type Z interface {
    echo() string
}

func (x X) echo() string {
    return x.Color
}

func TestFindCars(t *testing.T) {
    var err error
    var client *mongo.Client
    var collection *mongo.Collection
    var cur mongo.Cursor
    var ctx = context.Background()
    if client, err = mongo.Connect(ctx, "mongodb://localhost/so?replicaSet=replset"); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    collection = client.Database("so").Collection(collectionName)
    collection.InsertOne(ctx, bson.M{"color": "Red"})
    if cur, err = collection.Find(ctx, bson.M{}); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer cur.Close(ctx)
    for cur.Next(ctx) {
        var el X
        if err = cur.Decode(&el); err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
        }
        t.Log(el.echo())
    }
    if err = cur.Err(); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Test

```
$ GOCACHE=off go test -v -run TestFindCars
=== RUN   TestFindCars
--- PASS: TestFindCars (0.09s)
    find2_test.go:49: Red
PASS
```

Comment: That's probably because there's no `y` field in the inserted document. I'm pretty sure if you insert a document like `bson.M{"color": "Red", "y": 12}` it would fail. My question is basically how to encode/decode the element when one of its field is an interface type.

Comment: If Z is `interface{}`, it still works.  Give an example of the Z.  I am not sure I understand what you try to do.

Comment: Edited my question with your example that shows the test failing, hope that clarifies it.

Comment: Yes, the edited code will fail because it can't unmarshal an integer to an interface with a method.  You mentioned you used mgo.  Do you have an example of mgo that works?

Comment: Sadly no, this is something I would've wanted to after the refactoring. What could be an idiomatic workaround for this kind of stuff?

Comment: An interface type is defined by a set of methods.  You can't use interface for any data type unless it's an empty interface.  An empty interface may hold values of any type.  Empty interfaces are used by code that handles values of unknown type.